# Idiomatic way to write long queries in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I am completely new to Laravel.  I recently wrote a database query that works perfectly that looks like this:

```
function search($keywords, $lang)
{
if(count($keywords)<1)
  return [];

$pages = DB::table('pages')
  ->select(explode(',','pages.id,pages.updated_at,pages.created_at,page_translations.title,page_translations.description'))
  ->selectSub(function($query){
    $query->selectRaw("'pages'");
  },'content_type')
  ->join('page_translations','page_translations.page_id','=','pages.id')
  ->whereNull('pages.deleted_at')
  ->whereNull('page_translations.deleted_at')
  ->where([
    ['pages.published','=',1],
    ['page_translations.locale','=',$lang],
    ['page_translations.active','=',1],
  ])
  ->where(function($query) use ($keywords) {

    // Title
    $query->where(function($subquery) use ($keywords) {
      $subquery->where('page_translations.title','LIKE','%'.$keywords[0].'%');
      for($c=1;$c<count($keywords); $c++)
        $subquery->where('page_translations.title','LIKE','%'.$keywords[$c].'%');
    });
    // Description
    $query->orWhere(function($subquery) use ($keywords) {
      $subquery->where('page_translations.description','LIKE','%'.$keywords[0].'%');
      for($c=1;$c<count($keywords); $c++)
        $subquery->where('page_translations.description','LIKE','%'.$keywords[$c].'%');
    });
    // Block Content
    $query->orWhereIn('pages.id',function($subquery) use ($keywords) {
        $subquery->select('blockable_id')
          ->from('blocks')
          ->where('blockable_type','=','App\\\\Models\\\\Page')
          ->where(function($blockquery) use ($keywords) {
            $blockquery->where('content','LIKE','%'.$keywords[0].'%');
            for($c=1;$c<count($keywords);$c++)
              $blockquery->where('content','LIKE','%'.$keywords[$c].'%');
          });
      });
  });
$articles = DB::table('articles')
  ->select(explode(',','articles.id,articles.updated_at,articles.created_at,article_translations.title,article_translations.description'))
  ->selectSub(function($query){
    $query->selectRaw("'articles'");
  },'content_type')
  ->join('article_translations','article_translations.article_id','=','articles.id')
  ->whereNull('articles.deleted_at')
  ->whereNull('article_translations.deleted_at')
  ->where([
    ['articles.published','=',1],
    ['article_translations.locale','=',$lang],
    ['article_translations.active','=',1],
  ])
  ->where(function($query) use ($keywords) {

    // Title
    $query->where(function($subquery) use ($keywords) {
      $subquery->where('article_translations.title','LIKE','%'.$keywords[0].'%');
      for($c=1;$c<count($keywords); $c++)
        $subquery->where('article_translations.title','LIKE','%'.$keywords[$c].'%');
    });
    // Description
    $query->orWhere(function($subquery) use ($keywords) {
      $subquery->where('article_translations.description','LIKE','%'.$keywords[0].'%');
      for($c=1;$c<count($keywords); $c++)
        $subquery->where('article_translations.description','LIKE','%'.$keywords[$c].'%');
    });
    // Block Content
    $query->orWhereIn('articles.id',function($subquery) use ($keywords) {
        $subquery->select('blockable_id')
          ->from('blocks')
          ->where('blockable_type','=','App\\\\Models\\\\Article')
          ->where(function($blockquery) use ($keywords) {
            $blockquery->where('content','LIKE','%'.$keywords[0].'%');
            for($c=1;$c<count($keywords);$c++)
              $blockquery->where('content','LIKE','%'.$keywords[$c].'%');
          });
      });
  })
  ->union($pages)
  ->orderBy('updated_at','desc')
  ->get();

  return $articles->toArray();
  }
```

Basically this function receives an array of `$keywords`.  Then, then the query will look for any `page` or any `article` that has **ALL** the keywords in either the `title, description or content` within active `translation tables or block tables`.  I use a UNION to help me aggregate results from the two different content types and order by last update time.

When I look at this code, it does NOT look like the idiomatic laravel way of doing things.  It's as if I just wrote Raw SQL.  Can anyone suggest how I can use Laravel/Eloquent properly to perform the functionality above?

Comment: It is essentially raw SQL, because you're using query builder. Query Builder operates close to the SQL language layer. If you wrote it in Eloquent, you'd express the request in terms of model relationships. Such would remove much of this boiler plate and give you access to Laravel-esque features like scopes. Is there a reason you chose query builder over eloquent?

Comment: I will note that the distinction between Query Builder and Eloquent can be hard to see when you first get into Laravel. Those coming from SQL background, in my experience, gravitate toward query builder because it looks most familiar or are uncertain of the Eloquent ORM performance. I would suggst first modelling your tables and relationships in Eloquent, then adding scopes to express common constraints.

Comment: I'm new to laravel, so went with what I know.  I wasn't familiar with modelling those relationships and such, or concept of scope, and if there would be a performance cost, etc...

Comment: Oh also, there are some models already expressed because I'm actually building on top of https://twill.io/

Comment: @bishop if I use a more eloquent orm approach, do you know if the functionality I'm trying to achieve can be done with a single query to database?

Comment: Possibly, but your query is quite complex and I'd lean toward "no".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I prefer using QueryBuilder for complex SQLQueries and Eloquent for more casual stuff. Especially if it works already, I'd leave it with QueryBuilder instead of spending time porting the code to Eloquent.

However, you could still improve your code quite a lot. For example, this repeated line adds no value:

```
 $subquery->where('page_translations.title','LIKE','%'.$keywords[0].'%');
 for($c=1;$c<count($keywords); $c++)
     $subquery->where('page_translations.title','LIKE','%'.$keywords[$c].'%');
```

You could just rewrite it as

```
for($c=0;$c<count($keywords); $c++)
  $subquery->where('page_translations.title','LIKE','%'.$keywords[$c].'%');
```

Exploding a string doesn't add readability, you can just use an array instead:

```
select(['pages.id', 'pages.updated_at', ...]);
```

The `=` sign can usually be ommited:

```
->where('articles.published', 1)
```

So my conclusion is that if you just optimise this code, it will be fine and idiomatic.

Comment: Oh yes, the reason i'm exploded the string was because I was just copying over from a raw sql.  Which makes me think, if I plan to replace Laravel with Golang as a backend in a few years time, having raw SQL will make that much easier??? Thanks for catching the for loop issue, that was left over from another test I was doing

Comment: They say that optimising in advance is evil. If you plan doing something _in a few years time_, don't take it into consideration now. You can always log the raw sql query in case you'll have problems reading your own Laravel code.

Comment: There were a few other legacy projects on php 5.x that I had to migrate.  In the most recent one,  I helped with, I just moved all the raw SQL from `PDO::query($sql)` into stored procedures, and another developer just use Python/Django as a thin wrapper.  Those experiences really made me appreciate raw sql.  But i figure this time, i want to see the benefits eloquent/laravel can offer

Comment: As I've stated already, on this example you won't see much benefit using Eloquent; the subqueries will be the same (generated in a loop), you'll end up with pretty much the same that you have now except for minor improvements like `deleted_at` will be automatically checked for you.